# limit of sum of integrals is equal limit of integrals of sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f_n, g_n: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int f_{n}(x) d\mu$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int g_{n}(x) d\mu$ exists. Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int (f_{n}(x)+g_n(x)) d\mu$ exists?

That is true without the limit, but I am not sure whether that is true when we take a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limits are linear, as long as they exist.

So, by properties of limits (of numbers!) and the linearity of the integral,  you have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int f_{n}(x) d\mu
+\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int g_{n}(x) d\mu
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int [f_{n}(x)+g_n(x)] d\mu.
$$

What is not true in general is the converse. It may be the case that the limit of the sum exists, without the individual limits existing.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give an example for the other side, which is not true as you said?

Comment: Take any sequence $\{f_n\}$ such that the limit doesn't exist, and put $g_n=-f_n$.